# SO_ERROR vs. errno

Tags: c, sockets, unix, errno, getsockopt

For getting socket syscall (like `recv`) error, which is better (at performance level) ?

- Use the plain old `errno`
- Or use `SO_ERROR` as `getsockopt()` optname ?

I think `errno` (defined to `__error()` on my system) is faster because it's not a system call. Am I right ?

The advantages of SO_ERROR are : automatic error reset after getting, and we are sure that the error only concerns our socket. It's safer.

Which one do you think is better ? Is there a really difference of performance between the two ?

Comment: The point about SO_ERROR is that it remains tucked away safely in the socket data even after you've called other system calls ... such as `select()`, which can also set `errno`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quoting [Dan Bernstein](http://cr.yp.to/docs/connect.html):

> Situation: You set up a non-blocking socket and do a connect() that returns -1/EINPROGRESS or -1/EWOULDBLOCK. You select() the socket for writability. This returns as soon as the connection succeeds or fails. (Exception: Under some old versions of Ultrix, select() wouldn't notice failure before the 75-second timeout.)
>
> Question: What do you do after select() returns writability? Did the connection fail? If so, how did it fail?
>
> If the connection failed, the reason is hidden away inside something called so_error in the socket. Modern systems let you see so_error with getsockopt(,,SO_ERROR,,) ...

He goes on to discuss the fact that `getsockopt(,,SO_ERROR,,)` is a modern invention that doesn't work on old systems, and how to get the error code on such systems.  But you probably don't need to worry about that if you're programming for a Unix/Linux system released in the last 15 years.

The Linux man page for `connect` describes the same usage of `SO_ERROR`.

So, if you're performing asynchronous operations on sockets, you *may* need to use `SO_ERROR`.  In any other case, just use `errno`.

Comment: Dan Bernstein is incorrect about 'old versions of Ultrix'. The 75-second timeout is still there. select() notices a connection failure earlier if there was an *active refusal* by the peer, i.e. a response. If there was no response at all, the timeout still applies. The precise timeout period is platform-dependent.

Comment: @EJP: There *is no failure* until the timeout passes with no response.

Comment: @EJP I believe djb's point is that some old versions of Ultrix wouldn't report an active refusal (e.g. a RST packet) until the 75 second timeout expired, regardless of when the refusal happened.  That is independent of whether Ultrix or any other system reports failure after 75 seconds of no response.

Comment: And what about `exceptfds`? Microsoft says: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141(v=vs.85).aspx  "If a socket is processing a connect call (nonblocking), failure of the connect attempt is indicated in exceptfds (application must then call getsockopt SO_ERROR to determine the error value)." - is this exceptfds behavior Win-specific or does it work on *nixes also?

Comment: Historically, the only use of exceptfds  was to detect TCP out-of-band data. Whether some systems now use it for other things, I can't say.

Comment: AFAIK, Windows is the only system that uses `exceptfds` to report a non-blocking `connect()` failure.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting *Unix Network Programming*:

> If `so_error` is nonzero when the process calls read and there is no
> data to return, read returns –1 with `errno` set to the value of so_error
> (p. 516 of TCPv2). The value of `so_error` is then reset to 0. If there
> is data queued for the socket, that data is returned by read instead
> of the error condition. If `so_error` is nonzero when the process calls
> write, –1 is returned with `errno` set to the value of `so_error` (p. 495
> of TCPv2) and `so_error` is reset to 0.

So, errno is the better choice, unless you want to get error immediately before the data is fully fetched.